# Desabilitar seleção para linha do DataGridView c# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, datagridview

Olá, desde de já agradeço a atenção

Quero saber como desabilitar a possibilidade de selecionar uma linha de um **DataGridView**

> MeuDataGridView.Rows[Linha desabilitada].enable = false;

Já tentei o `Frozen`:

```
MeuDataGridView.Rows[Linha desabilitada].Frozen = true;
```

Ele bloqueia o `DataGridView` todo, podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tiver uma coleção com as linhas que não podem ser selecionadas, então pode fazer da seguinte forma (pressupondo que as linhas **1**, **3** e **5** não podem ser selecionadas):

```
List<int> linhas = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5 };

dataGridView1.SelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    if (linhas.Contains(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index))
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
};
```

Comment: A sim, obrigado 
Ajudou muito
Você sabe alguma forma para ao invés de selecionar a linha com o esquerdo selecionar com o click no botão direito?

Comment: Aí já não estou a ver como faria, a não ser recorrer a algum contorno mais "estranho" para o fazer. Mas de qualquer forma seria outra questão :)